# Irreducible subfactor inclusion and von Neumann type

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ and $N$ be factors and $N\subset M$ be an irreducible subfactor inclusion, i.e., $N$ has trivial relative commutant in $M$.

Does it follow that $M$ and $N$ have the same type?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the discrete decomposition of a type III$_{\lambda}$ factor $M$, $0<\lambda<1$, provides an example of an infinite-index, irreducible inclusion of II$_{\infty}$ in III$_{\lambda}$, i.e., we have:

$M = M^{\phi}\rtimes_{\alpha}\mathbb{Z}$,

where $\phi$ is a generalized trace on $M$, $M^{\phi}$ its centralizer (a II$_{\infty}$ factor), and $\alpha$ is the automorphism scaling the trace by $\lambda$.

Since $\alpha$ is outer, the inclusion of $M^{\phi}$ in $M$ should be irreducible by the relative commutant theorem(?).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

- if $M$ is type I then $M=B(H)$ and no subfactor can be irreducible.
- if $M$ is type II$_1$ it cannot have neither II$_\infty$ nor III subfactors (as these are infinite). And a type I subfactor cannot be irreducible: if $\{e_{kj}\}_{k,j=1}^n$ are matrix units in for $N$, then $\sum_ke_{k1}xe_{1k}\in N'\cap M$ for all $x\in M$.
- if $M$ is type II$_\infty$ then $N$ cannot be type III. If $N$ is type I then $N'\cap M$ is non-trivial as in the previous case. And if $N$ is II$_1$ then we can embed $N\otimes B(H)$ in $M$, and so $N'\cap M\supset 1\otimes B(H)$.
- if $M$ is type III, then $N$ cannot be type I nor type II$_1$ for the same reasons as in the previous case. And it cannot be II$_\infty$ either, because as you noted the inclusion $M'\subset N'$ would be an irreducible inclusion of a type III inside a type II.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Do you know of a good reference for learning about this? The material that I know focuses on subfactor inclusions of type II.

Comment: Many years ago I would have had a better answer, I guess, but I've never been a specialist and I've forgotten lots of stuff. From the Takesaki/Connes/Haagerup days in the 70s there have been many papers about type III factors, though not so many specifically dealing with inclusions. Longo's papers from the 90s could be a place to look, but there are others, too.

Comment: Why finite von Neumann algebras cannot contain infinite von Neumann algebras?

Comment: Because by definition a finite von Neumann algebra cannot have infinite projections.

Comment: How to show that if $M$ is type II$_\infty$, then $N$ can not be type III?  Is it correct that $N$ must not be $II_\infty$ when M is type III? Can we have following conclusion: If $N\subset M$ is the inclusion of factors, then type $N$ $\leq$ type $M$?

Comment: If $M$ is type $III_1$,  $N$ Can be type III$_{\lambda}$ or $(\lambda\in[0,1))$ type $III_1$?

Comment: You can definitely put a type III factor inside a II$_\infty$, since the latter contains a copy of $B(H)$; but not in a irreducible way. No idea about type III$_\lambda$ inside III$_\gamma$.

Comment: If we cannot have a irreducible type III factor inside type II factor inclusion that we also cannot have one the other way round, right? Just because $N \subset M$ irreducible implies $M' \subset N'$ irreducible.

Comment: Neat! I should have thought of that.

Comment: You wrote "if $M$ is type II$_\infty$ then $N$ cannot be type III". I don't really understand this part, could explain why this is?

Comment: I'll try to find a good argument (I don't have one  right now), but here is my intuition: $M=R\otimes B(H)$, with $R$ a II$_1$-factor. If $N$ is type III, then it has to be contained in the $B(H)$ "side", and so it cannot be irreducible.

Comment: What do you think of the following: Assume $N$ is a type III factor contained in a type II$_\infty$ factor $M=R\otimes B(H)$. If $N$ were to contain a projection that is finite in $M$ it would also be finite in $N$ which cannot be because of type III. Thus $N$ only contains the infinite projections of $M$. Can't this be used to show that the relative commutant is non empty?

Comment: But it doesn't have to be. $N$ could be of the form $1\otimes S$ or $R\otimes S$ with $S$ a type III factor. In both cases there are no finite-projections in $N$. In both cases, the relative commutant is non-trivial: $R\otimes S'$ and $R'\otimes S'$. But I don't see any reason to discard that $N$ might be inside $M$ in such a way that it is not a tensor product of subfactors of $R$ and $B(H)$.

Comment: Yes. You're right, that cannot work. There is a Theorem by Tomiyama that for subfactor inclusions of finite-index the types of $M$ and $N$ are equal. (I cou But not all irreducible inlcusions have finite index (right?). I think I'll post the II_infty, III case as a question on mathoverflow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, but at the same time not every finite-index inclusion is irreducible. Most likely in MO someone will be able to give you the (I'm fairly sure obvious) answer.

Comment: Yes of course. What's your take on Alexanders answer suggesting an irreducible II$_\infty$ in III$_\lambda$ inlcusion?